# Blur element in front of the image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, blur

Hy guys. I have this problem. So I have an image. In front of that image is simple  element with width and height. I want to blur that element so it looks like that part of the picture is blurred. I cannot have any image or background-image in that element. I want to achieve this effect without using any additional image, just css. I tried to put background colour, reducing the opacity and putting filter: blur but it doesn’t look good. I can still read the text that is supposed to be blurred.

Comment: filter: blur(5px);

Comment: like I said, not good since I don't have nothing to blur in that element

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/

Comment: Could you post some code for us to try a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this with full support without javascript, at the moment. But in case you want to support a limited set of browsers, you can use [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

> The **backdrop-filter** CSS property lets you apply graphical effects such
>   as blurring or color shifting to the area behind an element. Because
>   it applies to everything behind the element, to see the effect you
>   must make the element or its background at least partially
>   transparent.